# Joining Three tables at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple transaction types. Currently I'm only pulling the adjustments and payments, but I am needing to match the IDs of the types to their descriptions. For example, my transactions table has `paytype_id` and `adjustment_id` which range 1-100 for each. I have two other tables `dbo.paytype` and `dbo.adjustments` that have the distinct `paytype_id` and `adjustment_id` along with the `pay_desc` and `adj_desc` fields that describe what kind they are. Issue I'm running into is that any given transaction will only have a `paytype_id` or an `adjustment_id` but not both. So if I attempt to join one table, then the other I lose the NULL values of the secondary IDs

This query will pull the `paytype_id` descriptions but will remove any transactions with `adjustment_id` due to the `payment_id` being NULL for them.

```
SELECT 
    t.tran_num, t.resp_party_id, t.Total, 
    t.paytype_id, t.adjustment_id, t.clinic, 
    t.date_entered, p.pay_desc
FROM 
    adjpay_vw t 
CROSS JOIN 
    paytype p
WHERE 
    (t.paytype_id = p.paytype_id AND t.clinic = p.clinic)
```

So I'm wondering how I can pull both the `adj_desc` from `dbo.adjustments` and the `pay_desc` from `dbo.paytype`

Comment: Use LEFT OUTER JOINs instead of INNER JOINs (or CROSS JOINS with the join condition in the WHERE clause).

Comment: Does the view contain adj_desc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having your join condition in the WHERE, it forces it to behave like an INNER JOIN. Instead of using the WHERE, add it to the JOIN condition and flip to a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT t.tran_num, t.resp_party_id, t.Total, t.paytype_id, t.adjustment_id, t.clinic, t.date_entered, p.pay_desc, adj.adj_desc, ISNULL(p.pay_desc,adj.adj_desc) [Description]
FROM adjpay_vw t
LEFT JOIN paytype p ON t.paytype_id=p.paytype_id AND t.clinic=p.clinic
LEFT JOIN dbo.adjustments adj ON adj.adjustment_id = t.adjustment_id
```

Also, since I wasn't sure your view contained the adjustment description, I've added a join for that and added both descriptions and a new columns that shows the description no matter if it was an adjustment or payment.

Comment: No, my view didn't have the adj_desc already. This is exactly what I was looking for; thank you.